# problems while installing python-mysql package

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-python, easy-install

I've got an Ubuntu 12.04 x64 Server edition VM that I'm running python2.7 on and trying to install the MySQLdb package via the command (I've already got `easy_install` installed and working):

```
$ sudo easy_install MySQL-python
```

but I get the following traceback error when easy_install tries to compile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
      load_entry_point('distribute', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
      return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-1.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2393, in load_entry_point
      raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found
```

My `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` shows the following packages installed:

- distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg
- easy-install.pth
- pyinotify-0.9.4-py2.7.egg
- setuptools-1.1-py2.7.egg
- setuptools.pth

I'm not really sure where to go from here, or why I'm even getting this error.  I also wasn't sure if this question would be better suited for ServerFault; but, since I ran into this issue while working on some code, I thought maybe some other coders had ran into it before too...(seemed logical at the time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have installed `distribute` and `setuptools`, your `easy_install` script tries to load the entry point from `distribute`, but `setuptools` is found first.

You should remove `distribute`, as it has been merged back into `setuptools` and is now obsolete. Probably you'll need to reinstall `setuptools` after that to get everyting working again.

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo python distribute_setup.py
```

then run sudo easy_install MySQL-python again.